# Equation of electromagnetic waves solution, what are the parametres represent?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation

I am trying to understand the solution of the electromagnetic waves equation dervied from maxwell's equations.

I have been told that every function that is $f(\vec{k} \cdot \vec{r}
+\omega t)$ is the solution, and I can understand that, but I do not understand what each variable in the function is represent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*A* function is of the form:

$$ f(\vec r, t) $$

so the $\vec r$ is a position in 3D space, and $t$ is a time coordinate. Any function of the form:

$$ f(\vec r, t) = f(\vec k \cdot \vec r - \omega t) $$

is a solution of the wave equation. (Here I choose a minus sign instead of a plus sign in front of the $\omega t$ term. Both work, but this form provides a more common definition of $\omega$).

When you plug that form into:

$$ \nabla^2 f - \frac 1 {c^2} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial t^2}=0$$

you get an algebraic condition:

$$ k^2 - \frac{c^2}{\omega^2} = 0$$

so that:

$$ \omega = kc$$

provides a relation between the scales in time and space.

Since any function can be decomposed in to its Fourier components, choose:

$$ f(\vec k \cdot \vec r - \omega t) = e^{i(\vec k \cdot \vec r - \omega t)}$$

it's clear that $\omega$ is the angular frequency and $\vec k$ is the wave vector defining the wavelength and propagation direction (at speed $c$).

The combination:

$$ \phi \equiv \vec k \cdot \vec r - \omega t $$

is the phase, while $\omega = kc$ is the dispersion relation defining dispersion less propagation.